# Sketch.js how to export/import data (import as image, transparent lines are opaque)

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, sketchjs

I am using Sketch.js (http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/) for creating a simple drawing canvas.

I got a problem when I tried to load an image to canvas to take part of drawing (on my website user draw and save and after some thime can come back and edit), but I solved it by commenting the line `this.el.width = this.canvas.width()` at `redraw()` function, inside Sketch.js file as I saw on other SO question ([html5 canvas background image disappear on mousemove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869857/html5-canvas-background-image-disappear-on-mousemove)). Now the user can edit his drawing.

The problem is that after commenting out this line, when I am trying to set the color of the marker to be semitransparent (eg: `rgba(0,0,0,0.1)`), it is opaque (or converts to opaque when drawing another line).

You can check see this here: https://jsfiddle.net/1fhuwdb9/4/

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?
Thank you, all, very much!

Comment: Anyone? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you draw something, the image is redrawn by the script. Because you commented out that line, the old image is not cleared and now there are many stacked images. the script works and you are drawing transparent lines, but there appears many stacked layers, so the the transparent becomes almost opaque.

You don't need to comment that line to be able to import or save sketch's content. Inside the function, "this.actions" stores all user moves. You should only save it in a database, maybe as json, and then load it at beginning and call to draw.

To make this to take really part of Sketch, we'll add some funtions to sketch script.

Before `Sketch.prototype.download`, add this function:

```
Sketch.prototype.export = function() {
  $.post('yourfile.php', { data: JSON.stringify(this.actions) }, function (message_back) { alert(message_back); });
};
```

It converts all the actions to JSON and the POST to `yourfile.php` as `$_POST["data"]`, and alerts on the screen what you will print out in `yourfile.php`. In `yourfile.php` you should save `$_POST["data"]` on your server o inside a database.

Now, add this before `if ($(this).attr('data-download')) {` (you can find this at 3-4 lines before the new added function):

```
if ($(this).attr('data-export') != undefined) {
  sketch.export();
}
```

That will help you to make the export as simple as to download the resulted image (like `data-download`, but `data-export`):

```
<a href="#the_id_of_canvas_here" data-export=''>Save your drawing.</a>
```

Now, let's build the import functionality:

Add these lines after `this.action = [];` (you can find it around line 48):

```
if ($(this.canvas).attr('data-actions') != undefined) {
  // Load json and parse it
  this.actions = JSON.parse($(this.canvas).attr('data-actions'));
  // Redraw image by using the data
  this.redraw();
}
```

It gets the data from `data-actions` attribute of `canvas` element and parses it from json, adds the actions at the list of actions of the new image, and then draw the image.

Now, you just add `data-actions='HERE COMES THE JSON WHICH YOU SAVED ON THE SERVER ON DB'` to the canvas (Eg: `<canvas id="the_id_of_canvas_here" data-actions='HERE COMES THE JSON WHICH YOU SAVED ON THE SERVER ON DB' width="300" height="300"></canvas>`).

*Note: when you save the `$_POST["data"]` inside a file or database, don't forget to sanitize this ([Fastest way to check if a string is JSON in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041741/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-string-is-json-in-php) and [Sanitize JSON with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37533162/sanitize-json-with-php)).*